# Using rvm bundle install doesn't install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, rvm

I'm freshly using rvm for running a legacy project.

I installed rvm fine. Running `which ruby` gives the correct rvm version:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby
```

Then running `which bundle`, also indicates that bundle is using the correct rvm version:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/ruby
```

Now to get my project running, I run `bundle install`. It's important to stress on the fact that in my Gemfile I have
`gem 'rails', '5.0.7'`

Running `rails s` after those steps, gives:

```
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
```

Running `which rails` gives:

```
/usr/bin/rails
```

implying that the system version and not the rvm version is being used.

`echo $PATH` shows:

```
/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.5@global/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.rvm/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.pyenv/versions/3.7.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/bin:/usr/local/opt/libxml2/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/Mahmoud/.ebcli-virtual-env/executables:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

My question is, why hasn't rails been installed when I used bundle install? And why is `which rails` refering to my system and not my rbenv path?

Comment: What's the result of `rvm list`? Is there a `*` in front of `ruby-2.5.5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll bet your RVM isn't set up correctly and `/usr/bin/` appears in your `PATH` before RVM's bin directory. Run `echo $PATH` to confirm.

If so, back up your dotfiles for safety and run `rvm get head --auto` and it should put your PATH right. Logout and log back in or source your dotfiles (`source ~/.bash_profile` or whatever) and try again.

Comment: Great suggestion. This is not the case however unfortunately. I added the result of echo $PATH

Comment: rvm get head --auto caused and restarting terminal it worked. Thanks sooo much @Eric